# Mutate with different cut points by group

Tags: r, list, dplyr, purrr, cut

I would like to cut a numeric variable with different cut points for different groups.

I have tried combining into a list but I suspect I need some combination of function and loop. A similar example for recode can be found [here](http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/56636417), but cut will not accept lists.

Any suggestions?

Spreading into wide format is possible but I want to know how to do this in long format.

```
Cutpoints1<-c(0,1,10,100,9999)
Cutpoints2<-c(0,10,20,50,100,9999)
Cutpoints<-list(Cutpoints1, Cutpoints2) 
Df2<-Df1 %>%
group_by(group) %>%
mutate(varcat=cut(var,Cutpoints))
```

Comment: can you clarify what you mean by "cut"? You want to create a binary variable for each of the unique values (where "var" is greater than that value)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean the base R `cut` (which makes sense in context), you can use a couple of different methods, depending on how your group variable is encoded and how much typing versus transforming you want to do. (It's hard to tell what will be best given you haven't shown us what your data looks like.)

```
library(tidyverse)

Cutpoints2<-c(0,10,20,50,100,9999)
Cutpoints1<-c(0,1,10,100,9999)

test = tibble(
  numbers = seq(from = 0, 99.5, by = 0.5),
  group = rep(c(1,2),length(numbers)/2)
) 
## Method 1: ifelse
test %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  mutate(cut_group = 
    ifelse(group == 1, 
           cut(numbers, Cutpoints1) %>% as.character,
           cut(numbers, Cutpoints2) %>% as.character)
  )
## Method 2: get
test %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  mutate(cut_group = 
            cut(numbers,
                get(paste0("Cutpoints",group))) %>% as.character
  )
```

If you only have a few cutpoints, then the `ifelse` approach is a simple way to call `cut` to annotated your rows with manual references to each cutpoint vector. You have to call `as.character` because the factors produced by cut don't play well. (There may be a way to get rid of it within the function, too, but `as.character` will work in any case.) If, however, you have a lot of cutpoints, you can use `get` to grab the value of variables passed as strings, which I'm constructing with `paste0` here--you could `stringr::str_replace_all` if you have them encoded as "group1" or something.

In either case, you'll get this result using the test tibble I created:

```
# A tibble: 200 x 3
# Groups:   group [2]
   numbers group cut_group
     <dbl> <dbl> <chr>    
 1     0       1 NA       
 2     0.5     2 (0,10]   
 3     1       1 (0,1]    
 4     1.5     2 (0,10]   
 5     2       1 (1,10]   
 6     2.5     2 (0,10]   
 7     3       1 (1,10]   
 8     3.5     2 (0,10]   
 9     4       1 (1,10]   
10     4.5     2 (0,10]   
# … with 190 more rows
```

If you already have all of the cutpoints in a list of vectors, you would just call them with `Cutpoints[[paste0("Cutpoints",group)]]` instead of using `get`. Otherwise, it's not necessary to wrap them in a list.