# How to conditionally cut a dataset by group using a named list?

Tags: r, dplyr, subset

I have a dataset of survey responses from a large number of countries that I would like to cut up according to age ranges that are specified by census data (another dataset). I have extracted the age ranges from the census data into a list and converted them into vectors of breakpoints for each country.

I would like to use this list of breakpoints to convert the age variable into age_ranges (so I can ultimately compare the age breakdown of the survey data to the age breakdown of the census).

This is the code that I have so far:

```
age <- sample(18:50, 100, replace = TRUE)
group <- sample(c("group A", "group B", "group C"), 100, replace = TRUE)
df <- data.frame(age, group)

cutpoints <- list(group A = c(18, 27, 36, 45), group B = c(15, 24, 50), group C = c(30, 40, 50, 60, 70))

df %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  mutate(cut_group = 
           cut(age,cutpoints))
```

Where cutpoints is a named list. The names correspond to "group" (country in my case) and the cutpoints are vectors of the lower lower breaks by which I would like to cut the age variable. Again, these cutpoints vary from country to country.

The code above throws the error message `Error in sort.int(as.double(breaks)) : 
  (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'`

I have looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58997131/mutate-with-different-cut-points-by-group) post but the above code essentially follows the instructions but still results in an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can convert `cutpoints` into a dataframe and join it with `df`. We can then use `cut` to create separate groups based on range.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  left_join(tibble::enframe(cutpoints),by = c('group' = 'name')) %>%
  group_by(group) %>% 
  mutate(grp_int = cut(age, c(-Inf, sort(na.omit(first(value))), Inf))) %>%
  select(-value)

#     age group   grp_int  
#   <int> <chr>   <chr>    
# 1    41 group C (40,50]  
# 2    41 group A (36,45]  
# 3    22 group A (18,27]  
# 4    36 group B (24,50]  
# 5    19 group C (-Inf,30]
# 6    42 group B (24,50]  
# 7    40 group A (36,45]  
# 8    44 group B (24,50]  
# 9    29 group A (27,36]  
#10    33 group B (24,50]  
# … with 90 more rows
```

We can use `group` as well as `grp_int` as a group to calculate whatever information we need for each range of `age` values in each `group`.

Comment: I receive ```Error in findInterval(age, first(value)) :   'vec' must be sorted non-decreasingly and not contain NAs```. Could this have to do with the fact that I don't have cutpoints for all groups (countries)?

Comment: Also, how would I assign the actual captured age ranges to each of the observations? Like (18,27] or so?

Comment: I now receive ```Error in cut.default(., age, c(-Inf, sort(na.omit(first(value))), Inf)) : 
  'x' must be numeric```. Age and cutpoints are both doubles/list of doubles btw.

Comment: I am not sure what might be wrong since this does not error out on the sample data that you provided. Can you cut narrow it down to know which groups this happen?

Comment: @TeaTree For groups which do not have `cutpoints`, you don't have them in `cutpoints` itself or have `NA` as value for them?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210768/discussion-between-tea-tree-and-ronak-shah).

Comment: How would I add labels of the type "0 - 4", "5 - 9", etc? I was trying to use this code: ```labels = paste(value[-length(value)], value[-1]-1, sep = " to ")))``` but I receive the error ```Error in value[-1] - 1 : non-numeric argument to binary operator```

Comment: I think this won't work since the length is different for `breaks` and `labels`. Better option is to use regex to extract values from `grp_int` if you really want to give labels in that way.